# Laravel passport custom error message and status code when user unauthorized

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-passport

my project is running on `Laravel 5.4` and I use `passport` to make authentication via api with `bearer token`. everything works fine, but when unauthorized user tries to reach resource that require authentication, the user gets error message `405 method not allowed`
[image]

but I want response to be `401 unauthorized` .
 how can change this, and send only response with message, instead of exception? I did research, but couldn't find anything. I use standard laravel middleware for authorization `auth:api`. my routes grouped in middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  // these routes should return 401 if user not authenticated
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well method not allowed exception happens because you are hitting the wrong endpoint. You are posting to a get or vice verca.

However you can modify your exceptions if you go to `App\Exception` open up `handler.php in render()` method there you can adjust exceptions as you want example:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {
        return response('unauthorized', 401);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

On `handler()` method just check if `$exception` is instance of any exception object, if so you can modify the response as you want. For laravel exceptions follow [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Exception.html)

Comment: couldn't find the place where I can handle it. thank you!